# Is creamed butter stable for mid or long term storage?

Tags: baking, storage-lifetime, sugar, butter

I find creaming butter a pretty annoying process.
I would like to make lots of it at once and aliquot for later use.
Is creamed butter less stable than butter? You wouldn't think so because you are mixing 2 ingredients which virtually have no water (butter and sugar). Does it separate over time?
If indeed it is stable, is there a reason why grocery stores do not sell it?

Comment: Are you asking about butter creamed together with sugar?

Comment: Yes, I added clarification

Comment: Actually you can buy tubs of premade buttercream at most cake decorating stores? I don't buy it myself, but I believe you can buy it unflavored. That said, specialty cake decorating/sugar art stores aren't super common, but may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about butter creamed with sugar, you can do this.  I would place in an airtight container, maybe with a piece of plastic or wax paper on top, and refrigerate.  It should be good for a couple of weeks.  Of course, you will need to bring to room temperature to soften before use.

Comment: Whenever I store frosting, I put it in a freezer bag and then wrap in foil and freeze. Either way, it will benefit from re-whippong once it's at room temperature. (Not required, but generally recommended.)